# php artisan command not working using putty or ssh

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, ssh, laravel-5.3

**Can anybody help me to find out solution.**
**Problem:** php artisan command not working on server(using putty name.com) but showing result on my local environment (command prompt windows).
**Description:** when i am running php artisan command using putty it throws error in my error logs.

```
PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, null given, called in /home/hisunil4/intraview.co.in/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php on line 62 and defined in /home/hisunil4/intraview.co.in/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 103
```

Comment: site is running properly. but i just want to run some cron job but due to this problem i am unable to do such task.

Comment: Have you used any  ```url()``` or ```asset()``` etc helper methods in any of your configuration files?

Comment: @mquinn yes i used url() in my services.php for social login authentication as guided in socialite package of laravel.

Comment: sorry for the saying, but your website is getting error during the load time have you checkout it `Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection Object
(
    [routes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [allRoutes:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [nameList:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [actionList:protected] => Array
        (`
        )

)`

Comment: thanks @mquinn, i found problem you are right. problem of url() method in my services.php file in my config folder

Comment: thanks guys to find out issue specially thanks @mquinn.